# css: форму вывести вперед, тень на подвал

Tags: css, z-index

пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>



  <body>

    <form>
<p>
Text
</p>
<button>
Send
</button>
</form>
<footer>
  <a href="">ref1</a>
  <a href="">ref2</a>
  <a href="">ref3</a>
  <div>
  name
  </div>
</footer>

  </body>

</html>
```

css:

```
form{
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  padding: 10%;
}
footer{
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -20px;  
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: gray;
}
footer a{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;

}
footer div{
  text-align: right;
}
```

пример здесь: https://plnkr.co/edit/xYs5vBcm1sXcrHsVRJlm?p=preview

как сделать, чтобы подвал был за формой, чтобы она немного "наползла" на подвал и отбросила на него тень?

z-index не помог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

z-index прекрасно работает. Цвет фона поменял для наглядности.

```css
form {
  margin: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px rgba(0,149,225,0.8);
  padding: 10%;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99;
}
footer{
  margin: 0px;
  margin-top: -40px;  
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  background: gray;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
footer a{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2em;
  
}
footer div{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>



  <body>
    
    <form>
<p>
Text
</p>
<button>
Send
</button>
</form>
<footer>
  <a href="">ref1</a>
  <a href="">ref2</a>
  <a href="">ref3</a>
  <div>
  name
  </div>
</footer>
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @DmitryKondratiuk спасибо! странно, что z-index пересекается с position... нигде еще не натыкался на подобное